# Search through JSON array in PHP

Tags: php

If I add a php script that creates a JSON array with a unique ID like that:

```
$postArray = array(
  "input_ID" => date('s'),
  "input1" => $input1,
  "input2" => $input2
  );

$json = json_encode( $postArray );
$file = 'entries.json';

file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
```

How can I search through the JSON array and get the unique ID when I want to re-update it using another form?

Comment: Use `json_decode` to get array back and check it.

Comment: I did, but how do I check if the input ID is equal to the number it got registered with?

Comment: `if (ID == UniqueID)`?

Comment: @Raymond please put sample data of your entries.json

Comment: I don't have a variable called "ID" so if I am going to check it should look like that `if ($jsonDecode["input_ID" == the date it got set to])`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Please, start with php reference - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: @jameshwartlopez, basically I am just testing it so it's this: `{"input_ID":"5","input1":"test","input2":"test"}`

Comment: And you want to test what against what exactly...?

Comment: @deceze I have another form that will update the JSON file depending on the unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

You should not append JSON objects to a file. When you read in the file, you won't be able to tell where one object ends and the next one begins.

Instead, you should put all the objects into an array, and write the whole array to the file. When you want to add an object, you read the file, decode the JSON, push a new element onto the array, and write that back out.

```
$entries = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
$postArray = array(
    "input_ID" => date('s'),
    "input1" => $input1,
    "input2" => $input2
);
$entries[] = $postArray;
$json = json_encode($entries);
file_put_contents($file, $json);
```

When you want to find a specific entry in the file, you loop through the entries:

```
$entries = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
foreach ($entries as $e) {
    if ($e['input_ID'] == $input_id) {
        $found_entry = $e;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 


$file = 'entries.json';
//First, you need to decode it :

$jsonString = file_get_contents($file);
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$data[0]['input1'] = "TENNIS";
$data[0]['input2'] = "Outdoor game";
// or if you want to change all entries with input_ID "1"
foreach ($data as $key => $entry) {
    if ($entry['input_ID'] == '1') {
        $data[$key]['input1'] = "TENNIS";
        $data[$key]['input2'] = "Outdoor game";
    }
}

//Then re-encode it and save it back in the file:

$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents($file, $newJsonString);

 ?>
```

Comment: Tyyypooooooooo :) Look at the variable name in your if condition

Comment: I guess you mean `if($item->id == "80")`, since `$postArray` is an array.